# How to get access token for google analytics pageviews access our website

Tags: c#

I am getting google analytics "pageviews" our website but I have faced a small issue. Access token has expired. How can I generate a new access token for google analytics `pageviews`?

[This is my API URL](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&start-date=2018-02-01&end-date=2018-02-01&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&access_token=ya29.GltVBbw_VzYy6vgbk2LEJhh9O91-Ot6niIWHAhLmdWT1ZhyVce55xyE2mwOJHJa0AAB0QYl8PHFDz4eLiBdLuTORLLTjt4wwekroCpQKEBLz9xBUxtZQdK_ps6hl).

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#gaData",
    "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=2018-02-01&end-date=2018-02-01",
    "query": {
        "start-date": "2018-02-01",
        "end-date": "2018-02-01",
        "ids": "ga:xxxxx",
        "metrics": [
            "ga:pageviews"
        ],
        "start-index": 1,
        "max-results": 1000
    },
    "itemsPerPage": 1000,
    "totalResults": 1,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=2018-02-01&end-date=2018-02-01",
    "profileInfo": {
        "profileId": "123456789",
        "accountId": "123457854",
        "webPropertyId": "Tracking id",
        "internalWebPropertyId": "168908645",
        "profileName": "All Web Site Data",
        "tableId": "ga:xxxxx"
    },
    "containsSampledData": false,
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "ga:pageviews",
            "columnType": "METRIC",
            "dataType": "INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "ga:pageviews": "18"
    },
    "rows": [
        [
            "18"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-Using this API URL and Redirect URL is required.Go to Google API credential.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&include_granted_scopes=true&redirect_uri=http://localhost:52616/home&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxx-dsnsdngngdllsdglmlsdmg.apps.googleusercontent.com